# using the $sin^2x=1-cos^2x$,show that |axb| = $\sqrt{a^2.b^2−(a.b)^2}$

Tags: vectors

using $sin^2x=1-cos^2x$ in $|v|=|a|.|b|.sinx$, where  $v=a x b$ (vector product)

show that  |axb| = $\sqrt{a^2.b^2−(a.b)^2}$

ı dont understand what ı have to do exactly.
according to equation, must be Zero.

,so,Do I need to find the vectors what makes equation 0 ?
if I do,where ı have to begin the  solution ?

Answer (score 1):

$$|a\times b|=|a||b||sin{x}|=|a||b|\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}=$$
$$=\sqrt{a^2b^2-(|a||b|\cos{x})^2}=\sqrt{a^2b^2-(a\cdot b)^2}.$$

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: @Madness   You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$ a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cos \theta$$

$$ a \times b = |a| |b| \sin \theta$$

Square the two equations and add:

$$ (a \cdot b)^2 + (a \times b)^2 = |a|^2 |b|^2$$

Now you should be able to finish :-)

Comment: Do ı have to  find a and b vector as a numerical or just as an equation solution ?

Comment: Wdym by numerical? you have to rearrange that equation I wrote to reach final answer

Comment: ah ım sorry,now ı understand,thank you very much :)